# React API call to web API hosted on local IIS returns empty response

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to make an API call in React to a web API hosted on my local IIS. The API endpoint works fine. But the call returns a null array. This is what I have so far:

```
export default class MyRequests extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = { isLoaded: false, Data: [], error: null }
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/Request/GetRequest")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        Data: result.Data
      });
    },
    (error) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        error
      });
    }
  )
}
render() {
  console.log(this.state.Data);
  const { data } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>hi
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}
```

}

This is my JSON from the API endpoint:

```
{
  "CallbackFunction": null,
  "ContentEncoding": null,
  "ContentType": null,
  "Data": [
     {
       "ID": 0,
       "SiteTitle": "title",
       "SiteDescription": "test",
       "DateSubmitted": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
      }
    ],
  "JsonRequestBehavior": 1,
  "MaxJsonLength": null,
  "RecursionLimit": null
  }
```

I have enabled CORS extension on my chrome. Please let me know your thoughts

Comment: I didn't understand, is the API enpoint actually returning the JSON or is it returning nothing?

Comment: Sorry I was not clearer. When I hit http://localhost:8080/api/Request/GetRequest in my browser, I can see the JSON. When I call it through my React app, I can only see an empty array.

Comment: Try something run your React app on chrome and open developer tools by pressing [ctrl + shft+ C]  or F12 . See if any error is logged on Console or in the Network traffic. Pin the error to your question.